# DOMDocument: createElement before the first random tag found

Tags: php, domdocument

I have this code:

```
$html_content = '<p>text 1</p><p>text 2</p>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
@$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($html_content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'utf-8'), LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
```

I create new element this way:

```
$newtag = $dom->documentElement->appendChild($dom->createElement('span', 'Hello'));
```

The result is:

```
//echo tidy_repair_string($dom->saveHtml(), array('show-body-only' => true));

<p>text 1</p>
<p>text2</p>
<span>Hello</span>
```

But I need this:

```
<span>Hello</span>
<p>text 1</p>
<p>text2</p>
```

Any ideas?!

Many thanks!

Comment: Your example code does not produce the example output, are you sure both are exactly what you have?

Comment: Hi, sure. What exactly do you see??

Comment: @salathe you were right, I updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the parent node of these two elements -

```
$dom->documentElement->insertBefore($dom->createElement('span', 'Hello'),$dom->documentElement->firstChild);
```

So the idea is to insert the new element before the first child of the document element.

Edit: fuller example...

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$xml= "<body>
<p>text 1</p>
<p>text2</p>
</body>";

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);

$dom->documentElement->insertBefore($dom->createElement('span', 'Hello'),$dom->documentElement->firstChild);

echo $dom->saveXML();
```

gives...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<body><span>Hello</span>
<p>text 1</p>
<p>text2</p>
</body>
```

Update: If your using HTML as you say...

```
$html_content= "<p>text 1</p>
<p>text2</p>";

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($html_content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'utf-8'),
                LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Gives -

```
<p>text 1<p>text2</p></p>
```

Which is still not what your after.

Comment: Hi, I think it's the same answer from The fourth bird, but the output is: <p><span>Hello</span>text 1</p>. Span should be before <p>

Comment: Do you have an element above the `<p>` tags - as an XML document needs to have 1 top level element.  If you don't - it's probably using the `<p>` tag as the top level element.

Comment: Hi Nigel, Hi, I don't have the body tag, it's not XML. I load the code this way: `@$dom->loadHTML(mb_convert_encoding($html_content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'utf-8'), LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);`

Comment: If you have code that your using, it makes life so much easier it you had included it in your question.

Comment: Hi Nigel, thanks for your help. I updated the question. Your answer is almost correct, but the <span> tag does not appear at the beginning: `<p><span>Hello</span>text 1<p>text 2</p></p>`

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but if your importing a piece of text for HTML, would it work by simply putting the text you want at the start of the HTML before you import it?

Comment: Hi Nigel, thanks, I solved the issue using your solution and adding `<body>` tag to $html_content... I think DomDocument has some kind of issue with this. It's curious how something apparently so simple (set new tag as root) becomes impossible to accomplish.